# Can Samba pass user's password to an admin-defined script, upon user connect/logon?

Tags: server, samba, encryption

So I need to unlock an encfs directory (not home), with the user's password, when the user connects to the device via SMB.

The user has no other access - no SSH, GUI, etc. This would (almost certainly) need to be done via a server-side shell script that gets invoked by Samba, when the user logs on to Samba.

I know there may be sincere expressions of concern over security and best-practices, so just to head those off and not get sidetracked, let me say (or skip these bullets if you just want to answer the question as-asked):

- Thank you.
- I know this may not be "safe" standard IT client/server practice, as it could involve easily exploitable weaknesses (eg a script to hack).
- I know that encfs is riddled with known weaknesses, and the release version is not well-maintained.
- This is for a narrow, particular embedded use case - and a proof-of-concept at that. The gate - and only goal - here is to have **Samba unlock (or trigger doing so) a transparent stacked file-based encryption, with no user intervention other than connecting with valid Samba credentials**.
- Encfs or similar per-file stacked encryption-as-normal-files is a hard requirement. Whether that's EncFS, eCryptFS, CryFS, gocryptfs - in-kernel or user-space FUSE - doesn't matter at this point. (I'm aware that eCryptFS is abandonware, and that they all have pros, cons, weaknesses - as does stacked per-file encryption in general.) It just can't be LUKS, VeraCrypt - any loopback container - ZFS, etc.

If there's also a way to capture samba disconnect or timeout event at the server-side that would also be great, but not a deal-breaker.

The server is Ubuntu 22.04 Server. The client is any SMB3-capable client.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do that? I am also looking for a similar solution

Comment: Sadly, no. Or at least, not yet. I've been solving other technical challenges in the mean time and so put this one at the bottom of the stack - and also figuring out how I could just do without it. But this sure would be a sweet solution. I've dug through docs and googled until the cows crossed burned bridges to lie in the beds they made of cans of worms they opened, so far to no avail.